# Output session data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

How do I output the current session data.

This is my code in the controller

```
$this->load->library('session'); //load library of session; encryption key = key
$data['user'] = $this->session->set_userdata('email', 'email@hp.com');
```

The value that should be outputed in the view is email@hp.com
I tried this in the view.php but it is not working.

```
foreach($user as $row){
 $row->email;
 }
```

but it doesnt work. it says invalid argument.

Comment: `set_userdata()` SETS the session, doesn't GET it. And why are you looping of it, btw? It's not an array, it's a string

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('email', 'email@hp.com');  // set the session
$data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('email');   // get the session and store it in an array which is passed to the view
```

and in view file echo the value,

```
echo $user;
```

Otherwise, you can directly get the session value in view file like,

```
$objCI =& get_instance(); //now CI object can be used
$objCI->session->userdata('email');
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_userdata()` is used to set data in session, 
to get session data you should use `userdata()`

like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('email', 'email@hp.com');//to set data
$data['user']=$this->session->userdata('email');//to get sessiondata
```

And in view `echo $user;` will do.

[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)